# Merging Pictures in sequence

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am trying to make some kind of map maker, using the old 2D style of games such as Final Fantasy 4. Basically they had everything set up in a grid where each square on the grid might have taken 16x16 or 32x32 pixels.

I would like to start out small, and get the main things down first. Such as generating a map which could be, say, 128x128. This means, that I should be able to feed the program an array of numbers representing the different tiles available, and then the program should make a new picture by placing the tiles as the array specifies (So the one in Index 0 will be placed at 0,0 etc).

I plan to show the picture when I am done, but that should be easy as pie.

I've been looking around for a solution and all I could find was merging pictures on top of each other (as in layers on top of each other), rather than side by side, so can any one point me in the right direction? I'd like it if I didn't have to rely on 3rd party libraries, as this is more of a learning experience than practical application :)

Comment: *"I've been looking around for a solution.."*  ..what is the problem?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am stuck on the part of placing pictures next to each other, in one final picture. I can only seem to find people, who want to merge pictures like Photoshop does it. For example a picture of a product, and then a transparent map on top of it, to give it a nice glow. I can't find anything related to just placing bits of pictures next to each other in a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create the output `BufferedImage` to be the size you need.

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, imageType);

Then, get the `Graphics2D` object from the image and start drawing the smaller image in the places they need to be in the resulting image:

```
Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
for (BufferedImage img : images) {
  g2.drawImage(img, x, y, null);
}
```

Then, you can save the image to the desired format: jpg, png or gif.

```
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", file);
```

Comment: But I thought this would just place the pictures on top of each other, rather than in sequence?

Comment: If you use good values of x and y for the images, such as x + imageWidth and y + imageHeight doesn't overlap on another image x and y, then they will not overlap.

Comment: Oh. Well that's just what I am looking for then! Thanks a lot!